# Vue Draggable - How to get position of element being dragged

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am building a calendar day view, and I have cards that are draggable for events.

I am trying to workout how I can detect where the card is being moved to, I can detect the mouse position, but I need the position of the top of the element I am dragging.

```
<script setup> 
    import {ref} from "vue";
    import draggable from "vuedraggable";
    const appointments = ref([ // appointment data ]);

    function test(event) {
        console.log(event)
        console.log('ClientY = ' + event.clientY);
        console.log('PageY = ' + event.pageY);
        console.log('ScreenY = ' + event.screenY);
        console.log('LayerY = ' + event.layerY);
        console.log('OffsetY = ' + event.offsetY);
    }
</script>

<template>
    <draggable
        v-model="appointments"
        tag="ol"
        @drag="test"
    >
        <li>Appointment...</li>
    </draggable>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

`@drag` is the native HTML event. You should use `@move` emitted from the draggable component (https://github.com/SortableJS/vue.draggable.next#move). The event passed has the following properties (https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable#move-event-object):

- to: `HTMLElement`
- from: `HTMLElement`
- dragged: `HTMLElement`
- draggedRect: `DOMRect`
- related: `HTMLElement` — element on which have
  guided
- relatedRect: `DOMRect`
- willInsertAfter: `Boolean` — true if will
  element be inserted after target (or false if before)

So for you probably the most useful will be `draggedRect.x` and `draggedRect.y`